# How to paginate search results

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

```
<?php   
  function search() {
    $this->Table->recursive = 0;
    if ($this->data['Table']['search_text']) {
        $this->set('Table', 
        $this->paginate('Table', array('or' => array('Table.field LIKE' => '%' . 
        $this->data['Table']['search_text'] . '%', 'Table.field_2 LIKE' => '%' . 
        $this->data['Table']['search_text'] . '%', 'Table.field_3 LIKE' => '%' . 
        $this->data['Table']['search_text'] . '%', 'Table.field_4 LIKE' => '%' . 
        $this->data['Table']['search_text'] . '%', 'Table.field_5 LIKE' => '%' . 
        $this->data['Table']['search_text'] . '%'))));
    }
    else {
        $this->set('Tables', $this->paginate());
    }
  }
?>
```

How can I paginate the results of the method search() ?

Answer (score 0):

You have paginated it, the variable `Tables` will now hold the pagination.

I would recommend looking at http://book.cakephp.org/view/1231/Pagination to do with pagination.

If you specifically wanted the `search()` method to return the result of the pagination you could do:

```
<?php   
  function search() {
    $data = null;
    $this->Table->recursive = 0;
    if ($this->data['Table']['search_text']) {
        $data = 
          $this->paginate('Table', array('or' => array('Table.field LIKE' => '%' . 
          $this->data['Table']['search_text'] . '%', 'Table.field_2 LIKE' => '%' . 
          $this->data['Table']['search_text'] . '%', 'Table.field_3 LIKE' => '%' . 
          $this->data['Table']['search_text'] . '%', 'Table.field_4 LIKE' => '%' . 
          $this->data['Table']['search_text'] . '%', 'Table.field_5 LIKE' => '%' . 
          $this->data['Table']['search_text'] . '%')));
    }
    else {
        $data = $this->paginate();
    }
    return $data;
  }
?>
```

The return value of search will now hold the result of the pagination.